# Python GTK+ 3: Is it possible to make background window invisible?

Tags: python, gtk3

basically I have this window with a bunch of buttons but I want the background of the window to be invisible/transparent so the buttons are essentially floating. However, GTK seems to be pretty limited with CSS and I haven't found a way to do it yet. I've tried making the main window opacity 0 but that doesn't seem to work. Is this even possible and if so how can I do it? Thanks.

Edit: Also, I'm using X11 forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

For transparency Xorg requires a composite manager running on the X11 server. The compmgr program from Xorg is a minimal composite manager.